# How to select latest records less than value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named conductor. I want to select latest records that `date` less than `my_value`.

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | program   | date |
+----+-----------+------+
| 1  | program 1 | 1    |
| 2  | program 1 | 3    |
| 3  | program 2 | 3    |
| 4  | program 1 | 5    |
| 5  | program 1 | 7    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

If we consider `my_value` is 4 then output will be:

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | program   | date |
+----+-----------+------+
| 2  | program 1 | 3    |
| 3  | program 2 | 3    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

How can I select records by SQL?

Comment: Go on. Try something!

Comment: Why the record with date 1 is not appearing.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai : Latest Record for Date less than 4 is `program 1` with Date `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Conductor
WHERE `date` = (SELECT max(`date`) FROM Conductor
                WHERE `date` < myvalue )
```

Comment: This query will give the output for date = 4 itself!!

Comment: what will happen if myvalue is 5?

Comment: Note that date is not in fact a reserved word!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM conductor
WHERE date = (SELECT date FROM conductor 
              WHERE date < my_value ORDER BY DESC limit 1);
```

This should give you what you are expecting!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Conductor
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM Conductor
                WHERE date < myvalue )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,program   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,date INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1  ,'program 1',1),
 (2  ,'program 1',3),
 (3  ,'program 2',3),
 (4  ,'program 1',5),
 (5  ,'program 1',7);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----+-----------+------+
 | id | program   | date |
 +----+-----------+------+
 |  1 | program 1 |    1 |
 |  2 | program 1 |    3 |
 |  3 | program 2 |    3 |
 |  4 | program 1 |    5 |
 |  5 | program 1 |    7 |
 +----+-----------+------+

 SELECT x.* 
   FROM my_table x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT program
             , MAX(date) max_date 
          FROM my_table 
         WHERE date < 4 
         GROUP 
            BY program
      ) y 
     ON y.program = x.program 
    AND y.max_date = x.date;
 +----+-----------+------+
 | id | program   | date |
 +----+-----------+------+
 |  2 | program 1 |    3 |
 |  3 | program 2 |    3 |
 +----+-----------+------+
```